# Process in a while statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Im having problems trying to understand the complete process in a while statment in JavaScript, some doubts appear if I try to explain, step by step, how this code works:

```js
var myNumber = 2; 
var txt = "";
while (myNumber != Infinity) {
   myNumber = myNumber * myNumber;
   txt = txt + myNumber;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Doubts:

1.- "myNumber" and "txt" variables (those that are before the while) are modified in each loop of the while or only the variables inside the while are modified ?

2.- For example, in the **first** loop we have:

myNumber = 2*2 and txt = " " + 4

but in the **second** loop we have that:

myNumber = 4*4 and  txt = ¿4 + 16?

Is this second loop correct?

Comment: Yes, it's modifying variables that are defined with `var`

Comment: So in the second loop txt should be 20? but the console throws 16

Comment: Nop, `txt` is string, so it concatenates strings, not sums numbers. So in second loop it would be `"416"` (`"" + 4 + 16`)

Comment: Thats what i thought but the computer throw 20 (not 416) Why ?

Comment: Maybe you execute different code? I have put your code in SO Snippet and it works as I described

Comment: Is not 20 sorry is 16, instead of 416. Thats what i dont understand, is like if the empty string of the variable txt, get empty each loop cicle instead of save the values.

Answer (score 0):

Your demo code is okay for var/while system.
If you define your vars before the while and modify it in, it's okay. You will have your modifications after.

```js
var myNumber = 2; 
var txt = "";
while (myNumber != Infinity) {
   myNumber = myNumber * myNumber;
   txt = txt + myNumber;
}
console.log(txt); // "416256655364294967296184467440737095520003.402823669209385e+381.157920892373162e+771.3407807929942597e+154Infinity"
console.log(myNumber); // Infinity
```

But for your second loop, "¿" character is inavalid

Comment: Iits myNumber = 4*4 and txt = 4 + 16. The question mark is because i doubt about the result. I think ti should be 416, but when i execute the script it throws 20 in the second loop

Comment: "4"+16 === 416 ;  4 + 16 === 20

Comment: it was 16 instead of 20 sorry. Thats the reason is weird for me, the program throw 16 and it should be 416. Is like every cicle of the while the variable txt get cleaned. And i dont know why

Comment: Can you share your complete new code to see ?